# Convert a List<String> to a List<MyObject>, where MyObject contains an int representing the order

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there a pattern, or built in function I am missing or shall I just loop through like so

```
public List<MyObject> convert(List<String> myStrings){

    List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>(myStrings.size());

    Integer i = 0;
    for(String string : myStrings){
        MyObject myObject = new myObject(i, string);
        myObjects.add(object);
        i++;
    }
    return myObjects;
}
```

Its because I need to persist the list to a database and retain the ordering.

Comment: I can easily tell what this does, therefore its good code.  I'm not aware of any built in functionality for this...but if there was any I doubt that it would be any simpler then what you have just done.  If anything, it would be harder for normal people to understand.  EDIT: The Guava post just proved my point.

Comment: @Chad La Guardia lol, cheers, I will take that as a complement

Comment: Any particular reason you need to store the order in Java itself, instead of sending them to the database directly?

Comment: @glowcoder because they are individual hibernate entities, and I want to retain the order permanently

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29):

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = Lists.transform(myStrings,
   new Function<String, MyObject>() {
       private int i = 0;
       public MyObject apply(String stringValue) {
           return new MyObject(i++, stringValue);
       }
   });
```

Really it just brings the iteration into the library though.  In terms of actual code written, it will be about the same until closures are introduced with Java 8.

However, you should know that making the function stateful like this (with `i`) is bad form since now the order in which it's applied to the list is important.

Comment: Commons collections has a similar method: http://collections.sourceforge.net/api/index.html

Comment: @Mark Peters I actually like this, especially if the new list may not be read entirely, because it only does conversions as needed. One of those "free optimizations".

Comment: @Mac: Yes, that's a powerful feature of it being a "live view" of the underlying list.  However, that definitely highlights the danger of making the function stateful: you really have no idea in which order the function will be applied to values!

Answer (score 1):

Closures and lambdas that are coming in Java 8 should allow Java to have things like Mapper and Reducer functions(as in MapReduce). In fact, if you are following the latest developments from Project Lambda you would see lots of sample lambda code operating on collections.

e.g.

```
Collections.sort(people, 
                 #{ Person x, Person y -> x.getLastName().compareTo(y.getLastName()) });
```

But until then the code you posted in your question should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine. It's a little bit cleaner if you are using groovy because you could just do something like:

```
def i = 0;
def myObjects = myStrings.collect {str -> new MyObject(i++, str);}
```

Or Guava like Mark Peter's code. But, if you don't want to switch languages or import a new library, your code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo glowcoder's comment above and wonder why you need to transform the List -- which by definition has ordering information -- instead of simply persisting data to the database directly.

That said, I'll still offer a concise code snippet:

```
for (final String string : myStrings) {
    myObjects.add(new MyObject(myObjects.size(), string));
}
```

Comment: that doesn't do what I want though